# Proof overflow with carry our and carry in

Tags: math, digital

I have an exercise which I don't really understand.

> Prove that in a 2's complement number system addition overflows if and only if the carry from the sign position does not equal the carry into the sign position. Consider the three cases: adding two positive numbers, adding two negative numbers and adding two numbers of opposite sign.

I know how to count when adding who numbers, and how to see if the addition overflows or not, by looking at the carry in and carry out

But how will I do this proof in a general way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question shows few details and you show no work of your own, I'll answer with few details.

For each of those three cases (two positives, two negatives, one of each), consider the four sub-cases (carry into and out of the sign bit, carry into but not out of, carry out of but not into, no carry at all). In each case, show that some of those sub-cases are not possible. Then look at each sub-case and see if it means overflow.

Let's look at the first case--two positive numbers. First show that it is not possible for any carry out of the sign bit, so that removes two sub-cases. Then show that a carry into the sign bit (but not out of) is an overflow condition, and that no carry into the sign bit (and none out of) is not an overflow condition.

Then in each and every sub-case you will see that overflow happens when the two carries (in to and out of) differ and overflow does not happen when the two carries are equal.

This may not be the "general way" you were looking for, since you need to consider twelve combinations of cases and sub-cases, eliminating some and looking at the consequences of the others. But it does work. If you want more details, show more work of your own and I will be glad to add more.